# Why does North Dakota has a separate Timezone namespace in the Olson database?

Tags: timezone

When compiling a list of time zones, I wondered why North Dakota (along with Argentina) have there own separate namespace.

For example. Amsterdam has Europe/Amsterdam, London has Europe/London but North Dakota has their own namespace:

```
America/North_Dakota/Beulah
America/North_Dakota/Center
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
```

What is so special about North Dakota that it has its own namespace in the Olson database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many locations like these, where subregions (counties, provinces, etc.) have historical time differences.  You can read their history [in the comments of the tzdb sources](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2016i/northamerica#L378-L409).

The entries for the three North Dakota areas you mentioned are currently as follows:

```
# Oliver County, ND switched from mountain to central time on 1992-10-25.
Zone America/North_Dakota/Center -6:45:12 - LMT 1883 Nov 18 12:14:48
            -7:00   US  M%sT    1992 Oct 25  2:00
            -6:00   US  C%sT
# Morton County, ND, switched from mountain to central time on
# 2003-10-26, except for the area around Mandan which was already central time.
# See <http://dmses.dot.gov/docimages/p63/135818.pdf>.
# Officially this switch also included part of Sioux County, and
# Jones, Mellette, and Todd Counties in South Dakota;
# but in practice these other counties were already observing central time.
# See <http://www.epa.gov/fedrgstr/EPA-IMPACT/2003/October/Day-28/i27056.htm>.
Zone America/North_Dakota/New_Salem -6:45:39 - LMT  1883 Nov 18 12:14:21
            -7:00   US  M%sT    2003 Oct 26  2:00
            -6:00   US  C%sT

# From Josh Findley (2011-01-21):
# ...it appears that Mercer County, North Dakota, changed from the
# mountain time zone to the central time zone at the last transition from
# daylight-saving to standard time (on Nov. 7, 2010):
# http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/FR-2010-09-29/html/2010-24376.htm
# http://www.bismarcktribune.com/news/local/article_1eb1b588-c758-11df-b472-001cc4c03286.html

# From Andy Lipscomb (2011-01-24):
# ...according to the Census Bureau, the largest city is Beulah (although
# it's commonly referred to as Beulah-Hazen, with Hazen being the next
# largest city in Mercer County).  Google Maps places Beulah's city hall
# at 47 degrees 15' 51" N, 101 degrees 46' 40" W, which yields an offset
# of 6h47'07".

Zone America/North_Dakota/Beulah -6:47:07 - LMT 1883 Nov 18 12:12:53
            -7:00   US  M%sT    2010 Nov  7  2:00
            -6:00   US  C%sT
```

There are other more infamous examples, such as Indiana, which has 8 subregion entries in the tzdb, and a [detailed Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana) describing the chaotic history.